# what is the advantage of using input->post() rather than $_POST[''] in CI

Tags: codeigniter, post, input

I am a beggeiner in Codeigniter, I really wondering about using

> $this->input->post()

rather than

> $_POST['']

what is the advantage of using  `$this->input->post()`

Thank you

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$_POST[''] is not secure or unprotected


 $this->input->post() is secure. by defaults its FALSE instead of erroring.
```